# Git backend for Spring Cloud Server - how to ensure HA?

Tags: git, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to wrap my head around a question with the Git backend in Spring Cloud Config.

I have an on-premise cloud setup, using PCF. So my Config Servers would not hold state if restarted. In this scenario, what is the best way to ensure the Git backend would have HA? I understand that if I run a cluster of Config Server instances, that would resolve part of the problem, but what if they all crash at the same time and my Git server is down for some reason? In this case, the Git backend would need to have HA too (or at least a copy of the files would have to be available somewhere somehow for the Config servers to pickup). I imagine this is a very common scenario, so how are other people doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered this yourself:

> if I run a cluster of Config Server instances
>
> the Git backend would need to have HA too